# Azure Cosmos DB SQL API nested arrays query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need help with the following issue. I have the following JSON: (https://pastecode.io/s/sg2kJB0PLD)

```
"cities": 
[  
    {
        "name" : 'NYC',
        "neighbourhoods":
        {
            "buildings":
            [
                {
                  "grade": "A",
                    
                },
                {
                  "grade": "B"
                },
                {
                  "grade": "C"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name" : 'CHICAGO',
        "neighbourhoods":
        {
            "buildings":
            [
                {
                  "grade": "D",
                    
                },
                {
                  "grade": "E"
                },
                {
                  "grade": "F"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I need to check if any building has a grade that equals "F" by using SQL Query over Cosmos Db.

Any resources will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) function to achieve this.

Something like this SQL:

```
SELECT value r 
FROM r IN c.cities 
WHERE Array_contains(r.neighbourhoods.buildings,{"grade":"F"},true)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "CHICAGO'",
        "neighbourhoods": {
            "buildings": [
                {
                    "grade": "D"
                },
                {
                    "grade": "E"
                },
                {
                    "grade": "F"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you!!! If I could I would have marked it as an answer and upvote it.Can you share some good tutorials docs on this topic, because I need to learn what I am doing...

Comment: @Shiskachadokatumoji - tutorial / offsite resource recommendation questions are expressly off-topic here. Best not to ask for those. There are many doc pages for Cosmos DB, both from the team itself and from others. I would start by doing a bit of searching online.

Comment: @Shiskachadokatumoji Here is [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started) about SQL query. You can have a look. And you can test your SQL by using [Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21). There is no cost to use it. Good luck.